# Get current URL of UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, url, request, uiwebview

I already tried getting the current URL of my `UIWebView` with: `webview.request.URL`.
Unfortunately the `NSURL` was empty. Anything wrong here? I am working with Xcode 3.2.2 beta 5.

The code above should be executed in the `UIWebView` delegate `didStartLoad`.

Comment: Do that code currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString; after your web view loads so use - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView. Maybe this may help.

Comment: OP, considering this question has 78k views it's a pretty well referenced one. Would you mind updating the accepted answer to the heavily more up-voted one to prevent future confusion? Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### [Matt's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654403/2057171) is much cleaner. I recommend everyone to use [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654403/2057171) one instead of this

You could try this:

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
```

Comment: Thanks. My code above works when executing in didFinishLoad....
Somewhere I've read that the js version doesn't work on every page.
But I'll try.

Comment: Matt his version is much cleaner. So yeah I recommend everyone to use that one instead of this.

Comment: This is the only way it works for example in m.youtube.com. All other answers return wrong URLs.

Comment: I actually evaluate "document.URL" and not "window.location" (which was always blank for me). This is useful for internal adjustments to the page URL on JS heavy sites that might not use traditional page loads.

Comment: To the two people above - Aubada Taljo and Taranfx - Rengers has noted quite boldly (literally, the text is bold) and humbly that people should use Matt's version with more than 230 likes on it below. Clearly at the time of answering this, it worked and was accepted and 30+ people felt it worked too. This is now 5.5 years old. Good stuff, Rengers. Thanks for pointing people to Matt's answer below.

Answer (score 316):

window.location via JS didn't work reliably for me, but this did:

```
currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Credit:
http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-url-from-uiwebview.html

Comment: You will get incorrect url if you site will load some ads in other request. More clear variant wrote by `Mark Sands`

Comment: does not work for search results of google. While accessing search results from google it is showing me google URL not search result page url. Any help.........

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Google probably uses "HTML5" push state to manipulate the URL which doesn't involve executing another request (so currentWebView.request isn't updated).

Comment: @danw : Thanks for reply...But what to do in this case. Thanks again

Comment: @iOSDeveloper See the answer by SarahR above

Comment: Couldn't you then access the url referrer?

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work if the website has done a history.pushState

Comment: looks like this webview.request doesn't update on automatic redirects. It remains the one with which the navigation has started.

Comment: In Swift 4: webView.request?.mainDocumentURL?.absoluteString

Answer (score 55):

here's the code I use to grab the url every time you navigate to a different link within the webview:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
  self.url = aWebView.request.mainDocumentURL;
}
```

Comment: when I try this, the method is never called. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: @greg make sure you set yourself as the UIWebView's delegate

Comment: this worked for me while `webView.request.URL.absoluteString` returned `nil`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well and it's better than currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;

Answer (score 36):

I too found that the approved answer above was not reliable.
But with a slight modification, it seems to work every time:

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];
```

Note the addition of ".href" to the Javascript as this is hidden at the end of the line of code.

Comment: Thanks SarahR, your method works even if UIWebView loaded a page just partly.

Answer (score 18):

This is not correct, and will return a nil:

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];
```

However, the code below can get a URL, but the url may not be the current URL:

```
NSString *url = _webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

The correct one is:

```
NSString *currentURL = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];
```

Answer (score 8):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     NSURL *currentURL = [[webView request] URL];
     NSLog(@"%@",[currentURL description]);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried this for google search results on iPhone:

```
 NSString* currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
 NSString* mainDocumentURL = webView.request.mainDocumentURL.absoluteString;
```

Both return the same string!

Answer (score 4):

As UIWebView is deprecated, for [WKWebview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) to get the current url is very simple.

```
webView.url
```

Answer (score 3):

here the code i use :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[webView request] URL] absoluteString]]];
```

Comment: You are creating an NSURL by getting the string from an existing NSURL; couldn't you just copy `webView.request.URL`?

Answer (score 2):

I use the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` event (UIWebViewDelegate) to catch URL updates. `request.mainDocumentURL.absoluteString` will get you the main web page's URL (which is normally what you want), while `request.URL.absoluteString` will include CSS and JavaScript includes.

Answer (score 2):

implement delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString  *URL = request.URL.absoluteString;    NSLog(@"%@",URL);
}
```

URL is the what you exactly needed.

Answer (score 2):

This always works . .

```
NSString* url= [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];
```

Answer (score 1):

IN **Swift** try this,

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
    println(WebView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get current URL of the WKWebView and UIWebview

Here is the code.

```
if (self.wkWebView) {
   NSString  *URL = self.wkWebView.title;
}else if(self.uiWebView) {
   NSString *URL = self.uiWebView.request.title;
}
```