# Detect if UIWebView is showing www.example.com link

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

How can I do an if statement to check if UIWebView is displaying a certain page or not?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
NSLog(@"%@",([currentURL isEqualToString:desiredURL] ? @"YES" : @"NO")];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the url property of the request - see [SO for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491410/get-current-url-of-uiwebview)
But I'm not sure how you could handle different encodings of the same URL or IP addresses instead of FQDN's.