# How to Constantly monitor response headers with UIWebview for iOS App

Tags: ios, http-headers, rubymotion

I have a UIWebview in my iOS app that needs to monitor the response headers for each page it goes to, I have tried to look for it on

```
webViewDidFinishLoad
```

and

```
shouldStartLoadWithRequest
```

but have not gotten far, further research has lead me to

```
didReceiveResponse
```

for NSURLConnection, but my understanding is that this can only get the first response, and can not get the second, or further responses.

If it would help any, I'm using Rubymotion to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, I'm afraid. You can get the current web URL using JavaScript:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494051/204044

(or anything else that JS can access, for that matter)...but you're not able to get the headers. This is a security thing.

If you have control over the web server, you could pass in information that you need in a javascript object like this:

```
// In your webserver's code, assuming it's PHP:
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.customDataString = "<?= $custom_data ?>";
</script>

// In Objective-C
NSString *customDataString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.customDataString"];
```

Comment: yes, for my case I'm implementing the back-end so I have full control over the server, Javascript object did not occur to me, trying that out right now

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar by using AFNetworking.

I use [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) to capture all the link clicked by users. I return NO at shouldStartLoadWithRequest so the UIWebview will stay idle. Then, I get the NSURLRequest and get everything I need including HTML source by AFNetworking.

At last, I put HTML string back to UIWebView by [loadHTMLString:baseURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a).

User just appear to surf webpage as usual. They don't know I bypass UIWebview and just use UIWebview to display HTML.

Comment: Interesting and quite clever. Is this practice frowned upon by Apple at all?

Comment: We haven't touch Apple private API.
I have an app doing similar and only use UIWebView to display Motion JPEG. Apple approved it several year old.

Answer (score 0):

In delegate, register your custom NSURLProtocol subclass, then you can monitor responses with:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```