# UIWebView in a UITableViewCell open link in a browser.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a ViewController that have a UITableView. UITableViewCell have an UIWebView and I want to open links in a browser. I have set UIWebViewDelegate to my ViewController but method:

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

does not work. How do I open links in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a UIWebViewController ,and tell the Cell to push a new WebViewController in a tap action.

Comment: Because I need an UITableView where some cells are UIWebViews and some are not.

Comment: Have you set the UIWebViewDelegate properly? Show me the code.

Comment: Ohh. I have checked the code and I set delegate in a wrong place. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open your links in safari

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL[yourURL]];
```

### EDIT:

you can try this to get the URL from the webview all you need to do is to have access to that webview

```
yourURL = webview.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Found a related topic on this: [Get current URL of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491410/get-current-url-of-uiwebview)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I need to get that link from UIWebView that is in UITableViewCell somehow.