# How to get http:// address of page loaded in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have webView and send my cookies to my site for using same session (web store).

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame))];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

NSString *sessionId = [[OCRESTAPIClient sharedClient] sessionId];
NSString *value = [@"xid=" stringByAppendingString:sessionId];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MySite.ru/cart"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

User can walking on my site and i must to know where he is. How can i get web address of loaded page in webView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get current URL of UIWebview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491410/get-current-url-of-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make your class the delegate of the webview using

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Then override the delegate method,

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        print("current url is \(request.mainDocumentURL!.absoluteString)")
        return true;
}
```

This will give the current url going to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

use `UIWebView` delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  self.url = webView.request.mainDocumentURL;
}
```