# Ending Webview and going back to VIew Controller when URL changes

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have a edit photo php script that i want to load in my iOS app. I am calling it through WebView "www.example/com/myTool". When the edit task is complete the webView is moving to homepage of the website. I want when the Edit task is complete then instead of redirecting url to www.example.com/home the webView closes and it moves back to View Controller.

What i can think of solution is - when the URL of webView changes then the webView should close and move back to view controller .. But i don't know how to apply it in code.

```
import UIKit

class AddPostVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var addPost: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPost.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://new.example.com/pentool")!))

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate) methods.

Before loading a URL, UIWebView will call, ([webView: shouldStartLoadWith request](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview)) delegate method.

Compare the URL in request property with your home page URL. If yes, close the web view.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @KeshuRai I created a sample application with UIWebView and delegates for your reference.  https://github.com/mcabasheer/webview-reload pls check and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: thnx buddy .. but actually you have just stopped the webview from loading any other link .. what i want is when someone has ended editing the image then when he clicks on post button in php script , then after image being posted successfully the url should not redirect to www.example.com/home as the php script does, instead it should go back to home view controller.

Comment: @KeshuRai yes... returning false in that method will not redirect the webview to home page. and you can dismiss the view controller in that same block.

Comment: How would i tell my webview that the task that i wanted has been completed and now we can dismiss webview ?

Comment: You don't have to tell webview. Just pop navigation view controller and go back to previous screen.

Comment: M not getting it ... it wud b helpful if u can update your code and show it .

Comment: @KeshuRai  I have updated the github project with navigation example. Check for NSURL host property to get the domain name.   https://github.com/mcabasheer/webview-reload

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

`NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];`

This will get you the url of the current page. Or this

`currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString`

Credit to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491410/get-current-url-of-uiwebview/3654403#3654403`

Comment: can you explain it in swift please ?

Comment: Yup - so `currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString` actually is swift. Basically, it just gets the current url of the webview, where currentWebView is your webview. So in your case, you would go `if currentURL == urlYouWantToMatch { move back to view controller.}

Comment: Check out the link I posted, they go into all the detail you will need.

Comment: i tried your way. not working. url is not getting stored in currentUrl. Also the syntax has changed little bit .         let currentURL = addPost.request?.url?.absoluteString