# UIWebView get current URL of SPA (single page application) website

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiwebview, single-page-application

I want to get my `UIWebView`'s current location when browsing an [SPA (single-page-application)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) website.
<sup>(Yes, I am intentionally working with `UIWebView` instead of `WKWebView`.)</sup>

I know that there are [multiple approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2491410/3397217) to getting the current URL, such as:

```
webView.request?.url?.absoluteString
webView.request?.mainDocumentURL?.absoluteString
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location")
```

However, for an SPA website, for each of the approaches above, I am getting the initial url, even when I navigate to another page on that SPA website.

What can I do?

Comment: You can have a custom URLProtocol which intercepts all URL requests made within UIWebView to determine your current location (assuming you your definition of "current location" can be determined by URL requests).

Comment: You mean using the delegate methods such as `webViewDidStartLoad`? That doesn't work, because they're fired only once. When navigating to another page, they're not fired again.

Comment: nope, URLProtocol

Comment: Having a hard time implementing that. Could you show me how / point me in the right direction?

Comment: alright gimme a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Creating a custom URLProtocol to catch data requests**

```
class CustomURLProtocol: URLProtocol, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    // If this returns false, the first request will basically stops at where it begins.
    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        return request
    }

    override func startLoading() {

        print(self.request.url) // URL of Data requests made by UIWebView before loading.  
        URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil).dataTask(with: self.request).resume()
    }

    override func stopLoading() {

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

        // Data request responses received.  
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .allowed)
        completionHandler(.allow)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {

        // Data request data received.
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
        self.urlSession(session, task: dataTask, didCompleteWithError: nil)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {

            self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
            return
        }

        print(self.request.url) // URL of Data requests completed.
        self.client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Registering your custom URLProtocol**

Register your custom URLProtocol before loading your SPA in UIWebview.

```
URLProtocol.registerClass(CustomURLProtocol.self)
```

Hope this helps! Sorry for the delay, was caught up at work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I registered the custom protocol in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching` method. I can now see the requests & urls! However, the web view doesn't show load the page anymore.

Comment: Maybe you can share the URL of the SPA website? I might be able to help.

Comment: I manage to get the site to load, but sadly no additional data requests are being made within the site during navigation. Sorry that I could not be of any help.

Comment: Hmm too bad. Thanks anyway!